# Render blocking css in Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, performance, nuxt.js, nitro

Is there a way to remove render-blocking CSS from Nuxt 3 build. As I understand, Nuxt inlines all styles by default and adds stylesheet links for browsers to be able to cache it. That seem logical, but those styles are trying to load at the worst time possible, causing render blocking.

I have seen on other Nuxt 3 websites that they removed those style links all together to improve performance. But I can't find a way to do that.

Does anybody know how to remove them at all or delay their loading so they don't cause render blocking?

Thanks!

[Lighthouse Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEaHi.png)

[List of links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeiWM.png)

[List of links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MO4a.png)